# Best excercises without machines?

Tags: exercise, workout, bodyweight-exercises

for the next two weeks i won't be able to train with fitness-machines. What are the best excercises to train (with own weight)? I want to cover more or less the main parts of the body: triceps/bicepcs, stomach, back, leggs, shoulders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bodyweight exercisese are pretty limited but here are some good ones:

1. Push ups (chest, triceps & shoulders)

   1.1. Variations of Incline / Decline push ups.

   Oh, and try this challenge: [Bring Sally Up Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RU7O_DU_TQc) (*Bring sally up = Push Up | Bring Sally Down = Stay pressed down*)
2. Chin ups (biceps & back)
3. Pull ups (back)
4. Chair dips (triceps)
5. Squats (legs)
6. Lunges (legs)
7. Crunches (abdominals)
8. Burpees (full body)

If you want more suggestions, I found [this](http://greatist.com/fitness/50-bodyweight-exercises-you-can-do-anywhere), maybe it could help you out.

Comment: yeah it's limited ;) especially for biceps... btw good link

Comment: Bring Sally up, sounds hard but i'll try it. You also know one excercise for shoulders/breast?

Comment: @user1450 Bring Sally Up will destroy your chest and shoulders. Your triceps will be sore as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video in this blog post and you will see up to 50 different exercises that can aid in your endeavour.

http://trevoirwilliams.com/best-body-weight-exercises/